# Yocto bitbake Linux kernel config file location

Tags: kernel, config, yocto, bitbake

Where can I find the `.config` file used to build the kernel?

I use:

```
$ bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig to open the menuconfig
```

I just ran the `menuconfig` and I have a big problem : there are no activated option.
The .config file (?) looks deleted or broken

I have two directory :

- An old configuration of yocto with an up to date kernel config.
- A new configuration (I work on it) with a broken kernel config.

I have to get the old configuration file and paste it to the broken configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yocto finds kernel configuration in different ways,

1. defconfig inside Linux Kernel: You can specify `KBUILD_DEFCONFIG` variable in your recipe to use the `defconfig` which is already present in the source tree.
2. You can add your defconfig in `SRC_URI` of your linux kernel recipe or in `.bbappend` to your kernel recipe (may be in different layer).

If you modify the kernel configuration file using menuconfig as `bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig`, then bitbake switches does,

1. Find the default provider as in the variable `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel`
2. switches to `tmp/work/<MACHINE_NAME>-<DISTRO_NAME>-linux-gnuenabi/<PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel>/<KERNEL_VERSION>/linux-*build/` and run `make menuconfig` with according cross compiler prefix

If you are lucky and you haven't accidentally saved (twice) of menuconfig output, then you find your saved config as `.config.old` in the above path. Usually you will find two/three .config files,

1. .config : Current active configurations
2. .config.old : previous active configuration
3. .config.orig : Actual configuration from `SRC_URI`'s defconfig or in kernel defconfig options itself

Note: Kernel is extracted as source (during do_unpack) in `tmp/work-shared/<MACHINE>/kernel-source/` and linked to `tmp/work/<MACHINE_NAME>-<DISTRO_NAME>-linux-gnuenabi/<PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel>/<KERNEL_VERSION>/git`.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok in this folder :
`tmp/work/<MACHINE_NAME>-<DISTRO_NAME>-linux-gnuenabi/<PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel>/<KERNEL_VERSION>/linux-*/build/`

I have my .config 
Thanks a lot!